# how can i get a pop up message and redirect to url in php?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps

I have looked about but no answer that seems to suit my needs. Once a user completes a series of forms, i simply need a message to say thanks, confirm update and redirect to the main page.

code:

```
<?php 


require './facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => ' *************',
  'secret' => '********************',
  'cookie' => true, 
));

$status2 = $_POST['status2'];

$uid = $facebook->getUser();

$args = array(
    'message'   => $_POST['status2'],
    'link'      => 'http://apps.facebook.com/geordie-status/',
    'caption'   => 'Translate from English to Geordie'
);

if(isset($_POST['post']))


$post_id = $facebook->api("/$uid/feed", "post", $args);

    $msg = "Thanks for translating your status, it has now been posted to your wall.";

    header("Location: http://apps.facebook.com/geordie-status/");


?>
```

when the button is clicked, the update is posted, but there is no message box or redirect, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see any javascript to make a confirm, prompt, modal, dialog, etc popup....how do you expect that to happen without javascript?

Comment: ive had it work using the $msg on another php page i have, im guessing theres no way to do it using just php so when the OK is clicked on the message box it is directed?

Comment: Ehh, did you just post secret of your app? `*_*`

Comment: that was a total facepalm on my behalf, edited just before you posted

Comment: Damn, think before posting the code. Hopefully people here are honest enough not to do nasty stuff.

Comment: You're not going to be able to create a pop up with php alone. Javascript could do this very easily.

Comment: so what would be the best way to do it using js? i just cant seem to get the pop up and redirect to work together

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure that you aren't sending anything before your call to `header()`. If you have any whitespace before this code is called, or any HTML, then `header()` will not work.
If your environment meets the requirements for `header_register_callback` then I recommend you give that a try as well.

Also, after you use `header('Location');` you should call the `exit or die` function to prevent anything else from being sent.

If you were to do this redirect in javascript I would do it like a download page.

> 'Your download will begin momentarily. If your download does not start click here.'
>
> 'Your status has been updated, you will be redirected momentarily. Click here to return home.'

Javascript's `window.location` and `setTimeout()` would satisfy your requirements.

```
setTimeout('redirect',15000);

function redirect(){
 window.location='http://apps.facebook.com/geordie-status/'
}
```

If you want to use a hard message box then you should use `confirm()` for `yes/no` or `alert()` for just the message. Alternatively, you can use jQuery for popups.

```
var dialogResult =  confirm("Press Ok to confirm submission");
if (dialogResult == true){
   // post status
} 
else{
   // be sad and do nothing
}
```